# Clarification on where the logarithmic term came from?

Tags: real-analysis

Reading up on how to differentiate under the integral sign and an intermediate calculus book had  $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}(t^x) \cdot dt = \int_{0}^{1}t^x \log(t) \cdot dt$ written down. Was wondering if someone could explain where the logarithmic term came from?

Comment: It's simply by $t^x=e^{x\log(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Answered. Simple case of using exponent rule and chain rule.

Apply exponent rule: $a^b = e^{b\ln(a)}$ so $t^x = e^{x\ln(t)}$

Differentiate: $e^{x\ln(t)}$ using chain rule to obtain $e^{x\ln(t)}\ln(t) = t^x \cdot \ln(t)$

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. I replaced your `ln` with `\ln` for better readability.

Comment: Much obliged, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't have anything to do with the integral---it's just asking how to derive the derivative rule $$\frac{d}{dx}(t^x) = t^x \log t .$$
This follows immediately from rewriting $t^x = e^{x \log t}$, applying the chain rule, and the using the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$.